# Best way to check repetition of a char in a string?

Tags: java, string, repeat

Suppose I wanna know how many times this `.` is repeated in `127.0.0.1` String.

Comment: please see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: a workaround get the field value and check if it's more than 1 dot make it one :)

Comment: Thanks Anyway . Untill Now , I Used IndexOf & LastindexOf To Check For The Point 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this not an android problem it's a java problem any way you have to get the text  from the EditText as String and then check for the count of the .(Point) in the string

```
String line = EditText.getText.toString()
int count = line.length() - line.replace(".", "").length();
```

now if count is more than 1 it will make crash so give the user messae and stop the process else do what you want you are save

Answer (score -1):

It may not be the best solution but its one of the solutions. What you can do is; when user enters the double value, you can convert it into a String using Double.toString() method. and then you can check if it contains more than one '.' (dots).

Pseudo would look like this.

```
value = get double value from EditText()
str = value.toString()
checkFlag = check(str) //Checks if there are more then one dot
```

then you cna take decision based on checkFlag value